# PowerMock mock injected Authentication

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, powermock, spring-boot-test, powermockrunner

i am using `PowerMockRunner` in a spring-boot application for testing. Everything is working but when my controllers actions definition contain `someControllerMethod(..., Authentication auth, ...)`. Then `auth` is null and therefore some code is not working.

What i tried is to mock `Authentication` and `SecurityContext`. Came up with something like this

```
    private void mockSecurity() {
        Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
        SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        User mockedUser = new User("testuser", "passwordtest", authorities);

        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).thenReturn(mockedUser);
        when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).thenReturn(mockedUser.getUsername());
    }
```

Now those mocks work, if my code uses `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` method of accessing the authentication, but not for the one automatically injected (probably because it is not yet mocked when the controller mock is created).

Any ideas how to mock the injected `Authentication` so the code does not need to be changed? `spring-security-test`and `@MockWithUser` have the same result.

Relevant parts of the test look like this,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    UserController userController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserDetails() {
        mockSecurity();
        mockMvc.perform(...).andExpect(...);
    }
}
```

Edit as requested by pvpkiran the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void getDetails(@PathVariable String id, Authentication auth) {
    UserDetails loadedDetails = userService.getUserDetails(id);
    if (!loadedDetails.getUserId().equals(auth.getName())) {
         throw new Exception(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: show your controller class/method where you have this Authentication used. Without that it is hard to comment

Comment: Edited. But i think the core problem has nothing to do with the controller code per se. Simply the injected `Authentication` is null and shouldn't, rather it should be mocked.

Comment: checkt this out https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/testing-a-secured-spring-data-rest-service-with-java-8-and-mockmvc

Comment: Thank you but it uses a different test runner and a different test configuration. So for me that is not applicable.

Comment: you are missing the point. But the idea is similar. Doesn't matter which runner u r using. Main thing is `mockMvc.perform(
         get("/employees")
    .session(..)`